# Activity won't open

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I have a button that opens a new activity in Android, but it does nothing.

**Java for first activity:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.lists);


        }

 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   // ignore orientation/keyboard change
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


        ListView listsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lists);  
       Button newList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newlistbutton);
        newList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NewWishList.class);
                 startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
 }
}
```

**Java for second activity:**

```
public class NewWishList extends Activity {

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.newlist);

         Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
            back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ListOfLists.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });
     }
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  // ignore orientation/keyboard change
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

  RadioGroup option = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

}   
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.wish.list"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"/>


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <activity
        android:name="com.wish.list.FacebookSignIn"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<activity 
    android:name=".ListOfLists"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    ></activity>

<activity 
android:name=".NewWishList"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
></activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

No errors in Logcat or Error Log. It's very weird. The reason I have the onConfigurationChange is because I have it set to Force Portrait Orientation on. The activities are defined in the Manifest.

Comment: what's "v"? post your manifest.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman public void onClick(View v) which is in the OnClickListener for the button in the first activity. I'll post Manifest now.

Comment: put a breakpoint or debug log in the onClick method, its probably not getting called because onConfigurationChanged hasn't been called yet to set the onclick listener.

Answer (score 2):

First, try using

```
MyActivity.this
```

for the context.

Comment: so it would be new Intent(ListOfLists.this, NewWishList.class) ? That didn't work either. (first activity is ListofLists and second is NewWishList)

Comment: first, did you watch the logcat carefully when the activity starts? sometimes there are subtle problems in them manifest that don't show up in eclipse. second, are you sure the activity is not starting? is it failing on startup for some reason? third, are you sure the onClick() code is executed?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
v.getcontext()
```

try

```
getApplicationContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the IDE you're using? Probably Android Studio?
Do this.

1. Exit studio.
2. delete .idea\workspace.xml file
3. Relaunch and try again

Worked for me on Android Studio 1.0!